# Accumulating values from a listbox with a for loop instead of if statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, visual-web-developer-2010, listboxitems

I have learned how to accumulate totals with if statements and now I am trying to shorten up my code. 
A friend of mine told me that you can use a FOR loop to do this so I tried it out but I am having trouble understanding FOR loops completely.

My `IF` Code is this...

```
if (lbSnacks.Items[0].Selected)
{
    decSnackSaleTotal = decSnackSaleTotal + Convert.ToDecimal(lbSnacks.Items[0].Value);
}
if (lbSnacks.Items[1].Selected)
{
   decSnackSaleTotal = decSnackSaleTotal + Convert.ToDecimal(lbSnacks.Items[1].Value);
}
if (lbSnacks.Items[2].Selected)
{
    decSnackSaleTotal = decSnackSaleTotal + Convert.ToDecimal(lbSnacks.Items[2].Value);
}
if (lbSnacks.Items[3].Selected)
{
     decSnackSaleTotal = decSnackSaleTotal + Convert.ToDecimal(lbSnacks.Items[3].Value);
}
if (lbSnacks.Items[4].Selected)
{
     decSnackSaleTotal = decSnackSaleTotal + Convert.ToDecimal(lbSnacks.Items[4].Value);
}
if (lbSnacks.Items[5].Selected)
{
     decSnackSaleTotal = decSnackSaleTotal + Convert.ToDecimal(lbSnacks.Items[5].Value);
}
```

Of course, I commented it out to try to use the for loop. 
The loop I used is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbSelected.Items.Count; i++)
{
   decSnackSaleTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(lbSelected.Items[i]); 
}
```

`lbSelected` is my second `listbox` where the selected items go from the customer. 
`lbSnacks` is my first `listbox` where the snack selection is.

Thanks!

Comment: The for loop looks ok, could you provide a little more information as to what isn't working? I noticed you didn't use .Value in the for loop (but you did in you if statements). Was that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

That approach should do what you want, although you need to access the `Value` property in your loop too, similar to your `if` statements:

```
decSnackSaleTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(lbSelected.Items[i].Value);
```

This is functionally different than what your `if` statements are doing though.

- In the former case, you're only adding a value to the total if it was selected.
- In the latter case, you're adding all values regardless of whether or not the are selected.

You may want to check for that inside your loop.

There are other ways to approach the problem too, but this is at least better than checking every element one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you cannot convert the item to decimal, it seems you have to read the **Value** property as with the **if** approach.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbSelected.Items.Count; i++){
            decSnackSaleTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(lbSelected.Items[i].Value); 
}
```